# Overriding x-frame-options at page level

Tags: http, iframe, frame, x-frame-options

I am working on a .net application. There is an X-frame-options header included in the web.config file which is set to same origin. I want to override this for some specific pages to allow framing from some particular websites. Is there a way i can do this? If i set the header in html meta tag will that override the global setting?
I have referred a similar question [Overcoming "Display forbidden by X-Frame-Options"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6666423/overcoming-display-forbidden-by-x-frame-options) but this was posted way back in 2011 and there was a comment in the thread that mentioned this does not work any longer.